# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'tlsxyz'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm facing a random error when sending message from an Azure function to an Azure Service Bus (Standard) Topic.

the message error is:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'tls2576'., Stacktrace :
>   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.OnSendAsync(IList`1
>   messageList)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation,
>   TimeSpan operationTimeout)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation,
>   TimeSpan operationTimeout)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.SendAsync(IList`1
>   messageList)    at ServiceBusFunctions.MyTopic.Run(HttpRequest req,
>   ILogger log, ExecutionContext context) in    myAzureFunction

sometimes the object name in the error is 'tls2716'.

The code is running from an Azure function instance containing 3 functions. Tere are 2 redundant functions APP containing the same code called in round robin from an Application Gateway. The client code to send messages to the topic is:

```
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody));

//Custom properties for topis routing
message.UserProperties.Add("P1", P1);
message.UserProperties.Add("P2", P2);
message.UserProperties.Add("P3", P3);


ITopicClient topicClient = new TopicClient(SBConnectionString, CCTopicName);
await topicClient.SendAsync(message);
await topicClient.CloseAsync();
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem was closing the static topic client when a conccurent call is using it. the Fix is not to close the topicclient to reuse it and minimze the number of connection and tunning performance when open a connection

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to accessing the disposed objected after clearing from memory.

Comment: the problem is within the SendAsync method, this one is a framework method not my custom code